# Can you please help me find this angle between two vectors?

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

> Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ be non-collinear vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $|\vec a|=|\vec b|=\sqrt2$. Calculate the angle between vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ if the area of the parallelogram spanned by vectors $\vec a\times\vec b$ and $\vec a+\vec b$  is twice the area of the parallelogram
> spanned by vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

Can someone please help me solve this problem?
I understand that $|(\vec a\times\vec b)\times(\vec a+\vec b)|=2|\vec a\times\vec b|.$
But I dont know how to compute it.
Also vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ be non-collinear vectors so  $\vec a\cdot\vec b\neq 0$.
And $\cos\langle\vec a,\vec b\rangle=\dfrac{\vec a\cdot\vec b}{|\vec a||\vec b|}$.

Comment: Hint. The given condition boils down to $|\vec a+\vec b|=2$.

Comment: Another hint: Why is the cross product vector always orthogonal to any linear combination of the two vectors?

Comment: @insipidintegrator oh so you wanna say that angle between vectors axb and a+b woud be pi/2

Comment: yes. that's correct @Sunshine

Comment: Thank you @Intelligentipauca